# Strange strip at the top of Windows 10 (wpf)

Tags: wpf, xaml, caliburn.micro

I have this xaml on a project that uses Caliburn  micro :

```
<Window x:Class="Myproject.MainWindowView"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:cal="http://www.caliburnproject.org"
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="800" d:DesignWidth="1024" WindowStyle="None" Background="Black" >



</Window>
```

but when I run the application, I have a white line at the top of window :

[image: white strip at the top of window]

How can I remove the line at the top? 
I need a window that has no title bar, but should be resizable.

Comment: So because you're using resize + windowstyle=none you're still grabbing `WindowChrome` in the base style. See [this answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/539f0f4c-4057-4122-b0e5-3a01fbed8ea8/windows-10-wpf-window-with-windowstylenone-and-resizemodecanresize-is-showing-white-bar-on?forum=wpf) for more detail. Figured I'd just put it as a comment since it's just pointing you to another answer from elsewhere. Cheers.

Comment: @ChrisW. I think it may help a lot. Can I style chrome via c# code?

Comment: You can, but not sure why you'd want to. Embrace the xaml lol, on a side note though I think you can just slap the 'ol `AllowTransparency="True"` on your window properties so it's at least transparent, but won't be as obvious to the user of course. If it were me, I'd take it and make it my own, but I'm a design dork. ;)

Comment: @ChrisW.Allowtransparecy doesn't work as it stops the window from being resizable. but the xml worked well. Update your comment as an answer and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for the sake of easy points I suppose, the window chrome is built into the style templates and still inherited when you define `WindowStyle="None"` but still allow re-sizing to allow a hit spot for the manipulation event to occur. So like described in [another answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/539f0f4c-4057-4122-b0e5-3a01fbed8ea8/windows-10-wpf-window-with-windowstylenone-and-resizemodecanresize-is-showing-white-bar-on?forum=wpf) you can take control of the base template and edit it to your requirements while still retaining the ability for the user to have point to invoke the re-sizing ability but with the frame thickness set to 0.

Hope this helps, cheers!